# What's the best way to get the name of a folder that doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, directory

What's the best way to get a string containing a folder name that I can be certain does **not** exist? That is, if I call `DirectoryInfo.Exists` for the given path, it should return false.

EDIT: The reason behind it is I am writing a test for an error checker, the error checker tests whether the path exists, so I wondered aloud on the best way to get a path that doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you want some random name e.g. for temp folder? Otherwise I don't get what you want :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Name it after a GUID - <strike>just take out the illegal characters.</strike>

Comment: Does a guid contain any illegal characters? I just had a look and it doesn't seem like it does.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't really any way to do precisely what you way you want to do. If you think about it, you see that even after the call to `DirectoryInfo.Exists` has returned false, some other program could have gone ahead and created the directory - this is a race condition.

The normal method to handle this is to create a new temporary directory - if the creation succeeds, then you know it hadn't existed before you created it.

Answer (score 5):

Well, without creating the directory, all you can be sure of is that it didn't exist a few microseconds ago. Here's one approach that might be close enough:

```
        string path = Path.GetTempFileName();
        File.Delete(path);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Note that this creates the directory to block against thread races (i.e. another process/thread stealing the directory from under you).

Comment: This gets the path of a temporary folder, but if krolley wants something that would persist, this won't work.

Comment: True - but hard to know if this is a good or bad thing without more context. Actually, I like jop's Guid suggestion - if I can fix my openid I'll "up" it ;-p

Comment: AFAIK, in Windows, there is now way to wrap multiple operations in a single atomic transaction. So there really is no absolute answer to this. All we have are 'good enough' answers.

Answer (score 4):

What I ended up using:

```
using System.IO;

string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

(Also, it doesn't seem like you need to strip out chars from a guid - they generate legal filenames)

Answer (score 0):

Well, one good bet will be to concatenate strings like the user name, today's date, and time down to the millisecond.

I'm curious though: Why would you want to do this? What should it be for?

Answer (score 0):

Is this to create a temporary folder or something?  I often use Guid.NewGuid to get a string to use for the folder name that you want to be sure does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can be close enough:

string directoryName = Guid.NewGuid.ToSrtring();

Since Guid's are fairly random you should not get 2 dirs the same.

Comment: makes you wonder if there SO bots answering these quick and easy questions. :)

Comment: *matt thinks jop is actually a bot* ;)

Comment: *Fairly random* is one way of describing a Guid i guess... I suppose it depends on how many lives-of-the-universe you expect your system to be running for!

Answer (score 0):

Using a freshly generated GUID within a namespace that is also somewhat unique (for example, the name of your application/product) should get you what you want. For example, the following code is *extremely* unlikely to fail:

```
string ParentPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP"), "MyAppName");
string UniquePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(ParentPath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(UniquePath);
```